# remove numeric suffix

Tags: .htaccess, url

**The scenario**

We are moving an old site to a new joomla site
The old links need to line up to all work,  they pritty much do this exept for the following issue

**the issue**

The old links
/people/this-person-in-question-213

needs to now be

/people/this-person-in-question

losing the " *-213* "

we need to build a htaccess line to do this!  but have yet to make a working one

Comment: Can you show what didn't work? Is your htaccess working and you just don't have the right expression, or are you unable to do any redirection (is it enabled?)

Comment: very much like @anubhava answers,  I was going for detecting if trailing suffix is a number [0-9] and then if so ( as there always three numbers long ) removing the last 4 characters!

Comment: It would be interesting to see your expression - we might be able tell you why it doesn't work (and why @anubhava's does). You will learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your old site's `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+?)-[0-9]+$ $1
```

Comment: This seem's to have done the trick ! just running though the site now.